# How can I make the width of a page dynamic up to a certain limit?

Tags: javascript, html, css, xhtml

For example, dynamic and fluid between 600px - 1000px, but fixed at 1000px after 1000px and fixed at 600px below 600px.  Check out digg.com for an example.  I'd like a way that is cross-browser compatible. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is the code i used in a elastic-width with limits site to get it to comply - even on ie6 (the width:expression line is there for ie6):

```
min-width: 900px;
 max-width: 1280px;
 text-align: left;
 width:expression(document.body.clientWidth < 990? "990px": "auto" );
```

Comment: So max-width is recognized by IE6?  width:expression only needs to be specified for min-width?  Thanks!

Comment: no, max-width is not recognized by ie6 (sadly). that min-width expression is on a page wrapper div (lets call it container). then container is inside another wrapper (lets call it container2) that has the max-width expression below:
        width:expression(document.body.clientWidth > 1280? "1280px": "auto" );
        text-align: center;

Comment: so the full code for both divs is:
#container2 {
        width:expression(document.body.clientWidth > 1280? "1280px": "auto" );
        text-align: center;
}

#container, {
        min-width: 900px;
        max-width: 1280px;
        text-align: left;
        width:expression(document.body.clientWidth < 990? "990px": "auto" );
        
}

Comment: and the site i used for this example is http://www.olatheks.org if you want to check how it works.

Answer (score 5):

Use the [`min-width`](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_dim_min-width.asp) and [`max-width`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/pr_dim_max-width.asp) CSS properties.

```
body {
  min-width: 600px;
  max-width: 1000px;
}
```

IE6 doesn't support these properties, but newer versions (IE7+) do. All other major browsers support them.

Comment: I'm afraid IE 6 isn't supported. There are workarounds, however: http://www.doxdesk.com/software/js/minmax.html

Answer (score 0):

CSS is the way to go! This is a no-brainer. Try using a class like:

```
.style { min-height: 600px; max-height: 1000px; }
```